# Rails <ol> numbers reset at each page using Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

Have a news story display, similar to HackerNews, that uses an `<ol>` tag for numbering and vote ranking. When trying to paginate using the Kaminari gem the `<li>` numbers of each article get reset to 1-20 on every page.

I've tried using CSS counter-reset and counter-increment, but I cannot get it to work yet. I also tried manually adding counter-reset for each page, but if the site somehow sees more than 5 pages, I'll have to manually encode the increments, which isn't possible.

I'm wondering if there's a js solution.

Here's the index method of my **stories_controller**:

```
def index
    if params[:sort] && params[:sort].to_sym == :newest
      @stories = Story.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(20)
    else
      @stories = Story.order('karma DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    end
end
```

Here's my Story **index.html.haml**:

```
%ol
  - @stories.each do |story|
    = render partial: 'story', locals: { story: story, tag_type: :li }
= paginate @stories
```

And the **_story.html.haml** partial off the above:

```
= content_tag defined?(tag_type) ? tag_type : :div, class: 'story' do
  = link_to "⇧", upvote_story_url(story), class: 'upvote', method: :post
  %div
    .title
      = link_to story.title.titlecase, story.url
      %span.link-domain (#{story.url_domain})
    .metadata
      = statusline story
      |
      = link_to 'comments', story, class: 'comments-link'
      = "(#{story.comments.all.count})"
```

And finally my relevant CSS:

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
    padding-left: 2.0em;
    counter-reset: section;
    li {
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }

  li {
    float: top;
    counter-increment: section;
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help or new ideas!

**EDIT:**

Fixed this by taking out the Ordered List tag and switching to a Unordered List with list-style-type set to none to remove the bullet.

Here's the code I used in the haml view:

```
- if params[:page].nil? || params[:page] == "0" || params[:page] == "1"
    - x = 0
  - else
    - page = params[:page].to_i - 1
    - x = page * 15

  - @stories.each_with_index do |story, index|
    = content_tag defined?(tag_type) ? tag_type : :div, class: 'story' do
      %li
        .title
          .story_number
            = index + x + 1
          = etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue in the edit above..